# How to read avro from Java?

Tags: java, avro

I know you can read avro file from "filename", but how can I read from a URL?
I want to do something along the lines of:

```
URL file = new URL("http://mywebsite/my-avro-file");        
            DatumReader<GenericRecord> userDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
            DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(file, userDatumReader);
```

Comment: then assign `http://mywebsite/myavro.avro` to a `File` not `URL`

Comment: Very funny. I get an exception as the File cannot be a URL. "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: ah okay. take a look at this https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/how_to_convert.html

Comment: @Baby, does not work. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file". The link you shared appears to only work with "file://", but my case is "http://"

Comment: You might try using a [`DataFileStream`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.3/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileStream.html) which takes a `InputStream`, which you can obtain from a [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) using [`URL#openStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream())

Comment: A `File` represents a "file" on the disk or network drive and won't recognize URL's, as the mechanism for the management of those two resources is complete different

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are mad genius. Thank you! Post as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`DataFileStream`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.3/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileStream.html) which takes a `InputStream`, which you can obtain from a [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) using [`URL#openStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream())

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an own SeekableInput that reads from an URL.